# What is proper way to make replay a level in cocos2d game TO PREVENT TERMINATION?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I'm again stuck with the termination problem of game, this time it's beacuse of memory overflow I though, As when I replay the level, by following steps:

Step1: There is a menu button, on tapping which menu popup opens, this is achieved by a `push scene` that pushes a menu class ove the previous scene
Step2: In that menu popup, there's three buttons:
1.back to game which resume game from previous state, this is achieved by `popping up the scene`,
2.replay level,
3.back to home,

The last two are achieved by replacing the scene, which leads to **serious memory leak**, because the dealloc of the previous class doesn't get called, So, in allocation it shows memory increase of about 10-20mb, and no reduction. Which probably leads to termination of the problem.

How to overcome this problem? I'm badly stuck with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well what i did to over come this problem was an tricky solution:

Here are the steps:

step 1: made a global variable (flag) 
step 2: store action in that global variable, as to replay or to back home
step 3: pop up the pushed scene(that have released the memory of push scene)
step 4: check what flag is saying in schedule selector(to re-play, or to back to home)
step 5: replace the asked scene(that release memory of current scene)

This  is how I achieved it, any suggestion over it will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you aren't releasing something from your Scene. Dealloc is only called when the retain count of an object is zero. Have a look over your code and ensure that each of your objects is properly released when you're finished with it.

The Analyze tool (Cmd + Shift + B by default) in XCode 4 should give you a good idea what you're leaking.

Comment: No actually my problem is, i doesn't get that chance to release, As I call a pop scene on menu tap, and from that pop scene, the scene is been replaced.

Comment: If the scene you are popping has no other objects retaining it, it will be released. The objects of that scene should then be properly released in the `dealloc` method of that scene.

Comment: It happens the same as you say it, but memory allocated to the scene from which this popup arises, not been deallocated and the chunk of the same size be allocated again.. :(

Comment: are you using `pushScene` or `replaceScene`.

`pushScene` won't deallocate the scene because it's still on your scene stack.

Comment: yes I am doing that as I'm using a `pushScene` (and to `resume` game from it's current state I found It mandatory) then from `pushScene` class I'm using `replaceScene` to re-play the same scene and I'm unable to found any logic better to it..  And please tell more about (cmd + shift +B) as i failed to take benefit from it.